# QGIS: Clipping lat/lon points to raster file based on threshold value

Tags: raster, clip, intersect

Let's say I have an excel file that has a large number of lat/lon points that can be brought into QGIs such as:

[image: image1]

I then also have a raster layer that looks like the following:

[image: image2]

Each color in the above image represents a numerical value. For example, any color that is blue < 1, and green is < 2, yellow is < 3, etc. In QGIS, I go to 'Raster Calculator', and create a masked layer of instances where my raster values are less than 2:

[image: image3]

Now, I would like to intersect the lat/lon points that I have (first image) to where the mask = 1 (i.e., where the raster is < 2). I know there is a 'clip' / 'intersect' option for a vector field (instead of raster), but I cannot convert this raster to a vector field.

The final product would be a list / field of the lat/lon points (image 1) that intersect the Boolean mask (image 3) which is based off of values where the raster is less than 2.

Update:

Based on the answer by Babel, I right-clicked on the lat/lon points layer, and opened up the field calculator. From here, I entered the information provided:

[image: field calculator]

I then run the program, and the field calculator seems to have updated with everything in red, and there doesn't seem to be the correct points filtered. Perhaps I am overlooking something?

The sample lat/lonfile is below. Note, that the lat/lon coordinates are 'slat' and 'slon', respectively:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yxXKm0FBGQyYgBpiJ8CvBSOEs4iVo6Ep/view?usp=drive_link

The sample raster file is below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TML5182ZaeNoto7Y9XJS16OGo-yzbqGj/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Did you want use code or Raster / Vector processing tools?

Comment: The question specifically says I cannot convert to vector. But raster processing tools would be plenty fine.

Comment: The linked sample files can't be downloaded without an account. Can you share on a platform where download is possible without login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly, without creating any "boolean" raster using raster calculator. Get the raster value for each point and select those with a value < 2.

Use [Select by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#automatic-selection) on the point layer with this expression (see help for function [`raster_value()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#raster-value)):

`raster_value ('raster',1,$geometry) < 2`

Replace `raster` with the name of your raster layer. Use this to create a new attribute for the selected features or to delete the unselected features if you don't need them any more.

*Be sure to use the name of the raster layer as first argument as you can see here; yellow points are selected (<2), red points are not selecte (>=2):*
[image]

By the way: you provided your point layer as CSV file. Be aware that CSV files cannot be edited in QGIS. So if you use field calculator with the expression to create a new field, this will not work properly. Instead, export the file to a Geopackage.

Comment: I updated my post based on your response - this seems to have good promise.

Comment: In which band are the raster values? If unsure, select the raster layer , use the identify tool,  click on the raster and post the screenshot

Comment: The values are within band 1

Comment: I have added the raster and lat/lon file to the question.

Comment: original post is updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150839/discussion-between-miss-orchid-and-babel).

Comment: Works with your dataset, see updated answer with screenshot

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much for the help.

Comment: So the layername was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After Raster Calculator, you could run Polygonize (Raster to Vector) on each new masked layer. Menu => Raster => Conversion =>  Polygonize (Raster to Vector).
Open the new polygon layer attributes and add a Poly_ID or some other field that gives a Unique Identifier.
Then you could find the points inside each polygon using Menu => Geoprocessing Tools => Intersection.

This will generate a new set of points that will have a field of which polygon they are inside.

Then you can seperate the points by that field and export them.
[image]